# Display image description when using WordPress gallery shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

If I use the built-in (I think?) [gallery] shortcode in WordPress, add some photos, and click on a photo, I can set:

- Title
- Caption
- Alt Text
- Description

When I load my page and view the gallery, I can see the Caption value automatically inserted into a `<figcaption>` element right below the `<div class="gallery-icon">` element.

How can I similarly get the Description value inserted into my code? Is that somehow built-in, or must I use functions.php or some other method to extract that value?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48117/how-to-show-description-under-an-inserted-image.  Search through that site.

Comment: I don't think that works for the Gallery shortcode, i.e.: [gallery link="none" size="full" desc="1" ids="89,91,93,95,97,99,101,103,105"]

Comment: I ended up using this as the basis for the solution, but thanks for your help. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39241/get-all-image-from-single-page-using-this-query